# simultaneous diff-eq manipulations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

According to my instructor, I should be able to manipulate these differential equations:

$\dot{p_1} = -x_1 + p_2$
$\dot{p_2} = -x_2 - p_1 + p_2$

to solve for $p_2$ (not the derivative or integral of $p_2$), in terms of only $x_1$ and $x_2$ (time derivatives of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are okay in the answer, but not integrals).

Usually, I just solve an equation for a variable without a dot, take the derivative, do some substitutions, and these things eventually solve. But on this one, the more derivatives/substitutions I do the deeper I get...I'm not getting many cancellations.

Any help?

Comment: What are $\dot{p_1}$  and  $\dot{p_2}$ defined as? That is, are they constants?

Comment: functions of time

Comment: I'm guessing someone would have found an answer by now if there was one... Maybe I should turn this into a different question: Is there any way to prove that there is or isn't an answer?

Answer (score 0):

About your last question: "Is there any way to prove that there is or isn't an answer?". It seems that the answer is yes, because this system has exact solution for $p_2$, but it contains integrals of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

To find the solution, let us differentiate the second equation:
$$
\ddot p_2 = -\dot x_2 - \dot p_1 + \dot p_2.
$$
Substituting the first equation of the system instead of $\dot p_1$, we get
$$
\ddot p_2 = -\dot x_2 + x_1 - p_2 + \dot p_2.
$$
Hence, we get the following *nonhomogeneous equation with constant coefficients* for $p_2$:
$$
\ddot p_2 - \dot p_2 + p_2 = -\dot x_2 +  x_1.
$$
This equation has exact solution, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27-y%27%2By%3Df%28t%29 , or the general theory how to solve it (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Nonhomogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients). However, it seems that the solution contains the integrals with $x_1$ and $x_2$.